# A hostname with Unicode characters is valid in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-8

`Uri.CheckHostName("контосо.ком")` returns `UriHostNameType.Unknown` everywhere, but on Windows 8, where it returns `UriHostNameType.Dns`. Any ideas why all of a sudden a hostname with Unicode/Cyrillic characters is valid in Windows 8?

Comment: IDN support is actually a feature new to .NET 4.5, not Windows 8.

Comment: that wouldn't explain why the same .NET 3.5 application with `Uri.CheckHostName("контосо.ком")` returns different results on Windows 7 and Windows 8

Comment: Do you have 4.5 installed on Win7? 4.5 comes with Win8, and an exe targeting 3.5 will run on 4.5 by default.

Comment: makes sense, thanks Cory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of this. *Internationalized domain name*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5895

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to check whether IDN and IRI is enabled on 3.5?